# Does a Droid 3 support wireless charging?

Tags: motorola-droid

I tried using wireless charging with my Droid 3 phone, and the LED for charge indication started blinking. I wanted to know if this means that it supports wireless charging.

Comment: Are you talking about the [Motorola DROID 3 from 2011](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_droid_3-4036.php)?

Comment: Yes, it is the 2011 version

Comment: To my knowledge the first wireless charging phone was presented in 2012 by Nokia.